# Pointer To Char Array (cin.get & cout)

Tags: c++, user-input

Just to refresh my concept I'm working on parallel arrays. One is used to store integer data and the other one for char data i.e GPA.

The problem compiles like a charm but the result is not correct, it displays the Student IDs correctly but not the GPA.

- The simple `cin` works fine
- I don't really know how to use `cin.get` and `cin.getline` using pointers.
- In function `enter` I want to get the two-character-long string (plus one terminating null character).

Code listing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void enter(int *ar, char *arr, int size);
void exit(int *a, char *yo, int size);

int main()
{
   const int id = 5;
   const char grade = 5;
    int *student = new int[id];
    char *course = new char[grade];
    cout << "\n";

    enter(student, course, 5);
    exit(student, course, 5);

}

void enter(int *ar, char *arr, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        cout << "Student ID: " << i+1 << "\n";
        cin >> *(ar+i);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Student Grade: " << i+1 << "\n";
        cin.get(arr, 3);
    }
}

void exit(int *a, char *yo, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        cout << "ID And Grade Of Student #" << i+1 << ":";
            cout << *(a+i) << "\t" << *(yo+j) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: format your code properly and you are a lot more likely to get help!

Comment: Please rename your function 'exit' to something more descriptive.  thank you.

Comment: yes sir .. updating .. done

Comment: Why are you using pointers with `const int`, allocating it on the stack is much less buggy `int student [id]`???

Comment: Since you have C++ tagged, and not C ... why are you not using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: Argh, concurrent edits... :(

Comment: sir please have an eye on my code. i just want to do it in pointers .. that's all i will change the tag i'm sorry ... 
I really really sorry that i tag c++ ..

Comment: *"result is not correct, it displays the Student IDs correctly but not the GPA."*  What result would you consider correct?  What input did you give your program, and what result (***exactly***) did you get?  What did you expect?

Comment: i expect that if i enter C, A+, D, C-, B-
it should display it, but it displays some garbage char.

Comment: i just do not know, why people giving me the down votes, i'm here to get some help from you guys..
if i receive a couple of more down votes i will be banned, well that's a nice way to get banned huh .. Disappointing :(

Comment: @usman:  You are being downvoted because you asked a very poor question.  You posted a block of code, without reducing it to a [**SSCE**](http://sscce.org/).  You did not describe the input or output of your program, and you did not even ask question.  Please consider reading [**articles**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on [**asking better questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/), and consider how *you* would answer this question if someone approached you with source code and a poorly defined problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use *part* of the C++ language, but not embrace it entirely.  There is no need for you to manage memory (at all) to solve this problem.  Additionally, it would be much better to solve it using the standard language features:

```
struct Info
{
    int StudentId;
    std::string Grade; // this could easily be stored as an int or a char as well
};

int main()
{
    const std::vector<Info>::size_type SIZE_LIMIT = 5;
    std::vector<Info> vec(SIZE_LIMIT);
    for (std::vector<Info>::size_type i = 0; i < SIZE_LIMIT; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a Student ID:  ";
        std::cin >> vec[i].StudentId;
        std::cout << "Enter a Grade:  ";
        std::cin >> vec[i].Grade;
    }

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const Info& i)
    {
        std::cout << "Student ID:  " << i.StudentId << ", Grade:  " << i.Grade << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Which can very easily be converted to account for more than 5 (e.g. virtually infinite) by adding an overload for `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Info&)` and changing the for-loop to a `std::copy` operation.

If you absolutely want to keep your hands tied behind your back, you should at least make the following changes:

```
const unsigned int CLASS_SIZE = 5;
const unsigned int GRADE_SIZE = 5;
int student[CLASS_SIZE];
char course[CLASS_SIZE][GRADE_SIZE] = {};

// initialize course grades to empty strings, if you don't use the = {} above
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; ++i)
{
    memset(course[i], 0, GRADE_SIZE);
}

// ... 

// use your constants for your sizes
enter(student, course, CLASS_SIZE);
exit(student, course, CLASS_SIZE);

// ...

// NOTE:  you should check to make sure the stream is in a good condition after each input - I leave the error checking code for you to implement
cout << "Student ID: ";
cin >> ar[i];
cout << "Student Grade: ";
cin >> arr[i]; // also note:  since you are not using std::string, this can overflow!  careful!

// ...

cout << "ID And Grade Of Student #" << i+1 << ":" << a[i] << "\t" << yo[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Seems like you're also only embracing a part of C++ ;) You should at least check `cin` for errors; possibly use `push_back` and the second loop should be a range-based for loop.

Comment: @DyP  I left out the error checking to keep the sample code simple.  `push_back` is not necessary in this version as I used the fill version of the vector constructor.  And the `for_each` and ranged-based for-loop are both language features.  I typically prefer the `for_each` version as a matter of habit ;)

Comment: i know it can be done in many different ways .. 
i will be very thankful if someone help me with my code ..

Comment: @ZacHowland [An example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f88ee13caf3028ca) with very simple error checking. The reason why I recommended `push_back` is that it's far less likely to produce out-of-range access. It's not a problem here, but generally a good idea I think. (Also, it doesn't require DefaultInsertable.)

Comment: `memset` is not necessary. `int student[Class_SIZE] = {};` is sufficient for value-/zero-initialization.

Comment: @DyP:  It isn't student that is initialized, it is the course grade string (which I guess you could do with `= { { } };`?)  Either way, the character string does need to be initialized.

Comment: And I don't disagree with the error handling, but given the OP is resistant to using `std::vector` and `std::string`, switching to a potentially infinite (if they keep entering bad data) while loop is more complicated than just moving on ;)

Comment: Oops, yeah, `char course[..][..] = {};` ;) Aggregate-initialization is recursive, so you don't need additional braces. "but given the OP is resistant to using..." yeah... can't stop spreading "good practice" (or what I think is)

Comment: @DyP Personally, I would have preferred to do it this way:  http://ideone.com/6HLjOU  I agree with spreading good practice ... but you have to do it in baby steps for the noobies ;)

Comment: As a non-interactive solution, yes. If you run it interactively, you'll have to end input using a control sequence such as CTRL-D to insert an EOF. Providing a stream insertion operator for the output operation is certainly a good idea. As a matter of taste, I prefer calling it with the range-based for loop, because it's a bit shorter ;) and doesn't require repeating a type `for(auto const& e : vec) std::cout << e << '\n';` side remark: I forgot to reset the stream in my error handling D:

Comment: You need either that `EOF` or some other "invalid" entry in order to add an unspecified number of entries (or alternatively, you have to ask how many you plan to insert prior to inserting).  For merely academic exercises, I've always liked the Ctrl-D/Ctrl-Z (on POSIX) exit criteria ... and it makes the code very clean :)  I still haven't joined the bandwagon on the ranged-based loop syntax (and don't even get me started on `auto` - it is the first thing I really disagree with Herb Sutter on).